# When does a function space with compact-open topology have countable chain condition?

Tags: gn.general-topology

As in title，when a function space with compact-open topology has countable chain condition？ Are there some sufficient and necessary conditions？ Who give some references about this topic？

McCoy and Ntantu [Topological Properties of Spaces of Continuous Functions, Page 68]  pointed out that Vidossich had prove that $C_k(X)$ has ccc if $X$ is submetrizable. Who can give a proof of this statement?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't they give a reference ?

Comment: the given conference is [1972] Vidossich,Function spaces which are pseudo-aleph-compact spaces，preprint

Comment: That' s a bit obscure, indeed.

Comment: Just as an aside: $C_p(X)$ for $X$ Tychonoff (so pointwise topology) is always ccc, being dense in the ccc $\mathbb{R}^X$.